# how to write normal view to blade.php file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new in Laravel I want to write some php lines like :

```
<?php
    $uri_segment = "";
    $uri_segment1 = Request::segment(1);
    $uri_segment2 = Request::segment(2);

    $inventory_array = array('premium', 'surplus', 'purchase');
    $material_array = array('brand', 'style', 'pricegroup', 'grade', 'size');
    $product_array = array('adhesive', 'silicone', 'caulk', 'adhesivebrand');
    $suppliers_array = array('dropshipper', 'price');
?>
```

in blade.php file, so please help me, I was writing like :

```
{{  $uri_segment = ""}}
{{ $uri_segment1 = Request::segment(1) }}
{{ $uri_segment2 = Request::segment(2) }}
{{ $inventory_array = ['premium', 'surplus', 'purchase'] }}
{{ $material_array = ['brand', 'style', 'pricegroup', 'grade', 'size'] }}
{{ $product_array = ['adhesive', 'silicone', 'caulk', 'adhesivebrand'] }}
{{ $suppliers_array = ['dropshipper', 'price'] }}
{{ $system_array = ['webstores', 'utilities'] }}
```

but it's given error
[image]

please guide me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@php`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) directive in your view:

> In some situations, it's useful to embed PHP code into your views. You
>   can use the Blade @php directive to execute a block of plain PHP
>   within your template:

```
@php
    $uri_segment = "";
    $uri_segment1 = Request::segment(1);
    $uri_segment2 = Request::segment(2);

    $inventory_array = array('premium', 'surplus', 'purchase');
    $material_array = array('brand', 'style', 'pricegroup', 'grade', 'size');
    $product_array = array('adhesive', 'silicone', 'caulk', 'adhesivebrand');
    $suppliers_array = array('dropshipper', 'price');
@endphp
```

Comment: I am doing same thing of this code like : <?php echo $uri_segment == "users" ? "active" : "";  

        use App\Libraries\Commonlibrary;

$menu_list_view = Commonlibrary::sidebar_menu_list();
        echo $menu_list_view;
    ?> but given error ? how I can resolve it ?thanks sir.

Comment: @Naik This cache store does not support tagging. (View: /var/www/work/surface/resources/views/user-partials/leftmenu.blade.php)

Comment: @Naik  {{ $uri_segment == "users" ? "active" : "" }}
  at_symbol  php use App\Libraries\Commonlibrary;
        $menu_list_view = Commonlibrary::sidebar_menu_list();
  at_symbol endphp
{{ $menu_list_view }}

I am writing like this.

Comment: @NeerajPrajapati that means you are trying to set tags to your cache whilst the cache driver you use does not support tags

Comment: @Nike so what I should ?

Comment: You either need to change your cache driver or store just keys without tags. It's best if you post that as another question. Then even others will be able to help you

Comment: @Nike sir please see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786597/getting-error-this-cache-store-does-not-support-tagging-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown will work:

```
<?php
    $uri_segment = "";
    $uri_segment1 = Request::segment(1);
    $uri_segment2 = Request::segment(2);

    $inventory_array = array('premium', 'surplus', 'purchase');
    $material_array = array('brand', 'style', 'pricegroup', 'grade', 'size');
    $product_array = array('adhesive', 'silicone', 'caulk', 'adhesivebrand');
    $suppliers_array = array('dropshipper', 'price');
?>
```

However, you shouldn't do this in a Blade view. You should move the logic in controller or service class.

`{{ $inventory_array = ['premium', 'surplus', 'purchase'] }}` doesn't work because it's the same as doing this:

```
echo $inventory_array = ['premium', 'surplus', 'purchase'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> In some situations, it's useful to embed PHP code into your views. You
>   can use the Blade `@php` directive to execute a block of plain PHP
>   within your template:
>
> ```
> @php
>     // code here ..
> @endphp
> ```
>
> While Blade provides this feature, using it frequently may be a signal
>   that you have too much logic embedded within your template.
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#php