# when I add my new code then getting error "This cache store does not support tagging" in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I trying write code in blade.php in laravel but given error

[image]

my normal php code is :

```
<?php echo $uri_segment == "users" ? "active" : "";

        use App\Libraries\Commonlibrary;

$menu_list_view = Commonlibrary::sidebar_menu_list();
        echo $menu_list_view;
    ?>
```

I doing in blade.php like :

```
 {{ $uri_segment == "users" ? "active" : "" }}
    @php use App\Libraries\Commonlibrary;
        $menu_list_view = Commonlibrary::sidebar_menu_list();
    @endphp
{{ $menu_list_view }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel cache store does not support tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462365/laravel-cache-store-does-not-support-tagging)

Comment: @TharinduLucky when I add my new lines then it's given error otherwise it's working fine. so how can I resolve it? my new line is please see I doing in blade.php like

Comment: try `@php $menu_list_view = App\Libraries\Commonlibrary::sidebar_menu_list(); @endphp` or pass `$menu_list_view` as a view variable from the Controller

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#cache-tags):

> Cache tags are not supported when using the file or database cache drivers.

Comment: l didn't understand, when I add my new lines then it's given error otherwise it's working fine. so how can I resolve it?